# Error in brglm function: chol.default(crossprod(W.X)) : the leading minor of order 35 is not positive definite

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to fit the penalized logistic regression, as glm is giving me warning due to separation. I have found a package brglm, but it is giving me this error:

```
brglm_model = brglm::brglm(as.factor(y_train)~., x_train, family = "binomial")

Error in chol.default(crossprod(W.X)) : 
     the leading minor of order 35 is not positive definite
```

I have mix of continuous and factor variables in the data, none of them is with zero variance (those variables were removed in the beginning). All factor variables have 2 levels (none of the levels is empty).

Response variable is binary and intentionally balanced.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you multicollinearity?

Comment: Yes I do. What can be done about that?

Comment: You have to exclude one variable from the set of variables in the multicollinearity relation.

Comment: Might this be a problem also in normal glm regression, i.e. if VIF is Inf for some variables, can the separation occur due to this ? Thanks.

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Ah, I will try to play around with that. thank you!